# Javascript - Reflect.construct requires the first argument be a constructor (only iOS 13)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

My cross-platform vue app suddenly stopped working altogether on iOS 13, while still working just fine on iOS 14 and other platforms.

I added alerts to `window.onerror` and found out I have a case of `TypeError: Reflect.construct requires the first argument be a constructor (only iOS 13)` in my `chunk-vendors.js` file, where code is not really understandable.

I tried to revert `package.json` to a version from a commit where everything was still working, but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

A further look at `chunk-vendors.js` would eventually show you that the error is happening somewhere in babel's `construct.js`. To find out which class is causing the error, add a log/alert inside of `_construct` as such:

```js
export default function _construct(Parent, args, Class) {
  alert(Class); // <-- add this to find the culprit
  if (isNativeReflectConstruct()) {
    _construct = Reflect.construct;
  } else {
...
```

Now it is time to revisit the constructor of the class, and more likely the constructors of the **classes that it extends**.
In my case, I had a class that extends `EventTarget`, which is not supported on iOS 13.